# Add decoded(from Hindi) params to a given url in python

Tags: python

I have this url = 'http://www.bhaskar.com/uttar_pradesh/lucknow/='. after the "=" sign one Hindi word which denotes the word searched for is given. I want to be able to add that as a parameter to this url, so that I will only need to change the word each time and not the whole url. I tried to use this:

```
>>> url = 'http://www.bhaskar.com/uttar_pradesh/lucknow/='
>>> word = 'word1'
>>> conj = url + word
```

but this gives me the Hindi word in unicode. like this:

```
>>> conj
'http://www.bhaskar.com/uttar_pradesh/lucknow/=\xe0\xa6\xb8\xe0\xa6\xb0'
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you pass unicode in query like `queryword=\xe0\xa6\xb8\xe0\xa6\xb0`  what do you receive on server? i mean through GET parameter read of `queryword` ?

Comment: How does `'http://www.bhaskar.com/uttar_pradesh/lucknow/='` + `'word1'` give `'http://www.bhaskar.com/uttar_pradesh/lucknow/=\xe0\xa6\xb8\xe0\xa6\xb0'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but this gives me the Bengali word in unicode

No, it does not :)

When you type `temp` in the terminal, it displays an *unique* interpretation of the string. When you type `print(temp)`, however, you are getting a more *user-friendly* representation of the same string. In the end, however, the string pointed by `temp` is the same all the time, it is only presented in different ways. See, for example, if you get the second one and put it in a variable and print it:

```
>>> temp2 = 'http://www.cfilt.iitb.ac.in/indowordnet/first?langno=3&queryword=\xe0\xa6\xb8\xe0\xa6\xb0'
>>> print(temp2)
http://www.cfilt.iitb.ac.in/indowordnet/first?langno=3&queryword=সর
```

Actually, you can create the string by using escaped values in *all* characters, not only the Bengali one:

```
>>> temp3 = '\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3a\x2f\x2f\x77\x77\x77\x2e\x63\x66\x69\x6c\x74\x2e\x69\x69\x74\x62\x2e\x61\x63\x2e\x69\x6e\x2f\x69\x6e\x64\x6f\x77\x6f\x72\x64\x6e\x65\x74\x2f\x66\x69\x72\x73\x74\x3f\x6c\x61\x6e\x67\x6e\x6f\x3d\x33\x26\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79\x77\x6f\x72\x64\x3d\xe0\xa6\xb8\xe0\xa6\xb0'
>>> print(temp3)
http://www.cfilt.iitb.ac.in/indowordnet/first?langno=3&queryword=সর
```

In the end, all these strings are the same:

```
>>> temp == temp2
True
>>> temp == temp3
True
```

So, don't worry, you have the correct string in the variable. You are only getting a problem if the escaped string is displayed elsewhere. Finish your program, run it until the end and you'll see there will be no errors.